# Files hidden after copying from NAS to NAS using rsync

Tags: backup, nas, rsync

I have 2 Western Digital NAS: a blue light and a 2TB MyBook latest edition. I enabled ssh on the MyBook and I can use rsync from a terminal to sync files between the 2 NAS. Instead of copying using a laptop for copying between the NAS's (my laptops are connected to WiFi, the 2 NAS are in the Ethernet in the same router).

Later when trying to access the files from a Windows OS machine (Vista) the files are Hidden. I mapped the NAS share drive with a user that has full control. So from Windows I was able to change the attribute to visible.

**But how can I transfer files without doing this extra step on Windows?**

### Here the process in detail

So first I transferred using ftp from my laptop to MyBook connecting as root.

The files ended with permissions

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root ...

Without doing any changes to permissions I copied them using rsync connected as root via ssh in the MyBook to the other NAS. I couldn't hack my other NAS yet, so I have to mount the other NAS file system using cifs:

> mount -t cifs -o user=username,password=******** //IP-target-NAS/share /mnt/local-share/

The username I used to mount is a user defined in the target NAS via the UI. This is the same username I use to connect from my laptops to the Windows shares on that NAS.

If I do an ls -l the permissions are:

> -rwx------ 1 www-data www-data ...

If I check the permissions from other files, that I copied from NAS to NAS using the Windows laptop (a lot of time!), they are:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data

Answer (score 0):

Use `--perms` to preserve the permissions.

Check the man page section for `-p, --perms` to see what the default is and what -p changes.